# lookup table or something else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have 8 tables;

1. employees
2. employee_subjects
3. outlet
4. outlet_subjects
5. subjects
6. geography
7. outlet_geography
8. employee_geography

Now, I need to be able to search out outlets and employees within a range of different geographies and based on a range of subjets.

My questions is: Is there a good strategy and is it a good idea to create a somewhat static lookup table where I have inserted all the data I need in my range ?

The table would potentially grow to +50 million rows but I would be able to say

```
SELECT ... FROM lookup WHERE subId = 1 OR subId = 2 OR geoId = 1 geoId = 2...etc etc.
```

So I get to keep the joins out.

Vague, yes, but I need guidance on this!

Comment: Trying to understand: Do you want to encode your query parameters in that lookup table, or do you want to materialize the results from joining all your tables?

Comment: I want to put all the data I need to look up into one table alone.

Answer (score 2):

That question cannot be answered in general. In some contexts you have to keep redundant, denormalized data for performance reasons (in particular for data warehouses). However, you should not introduce redundancies or potential inconsistencies lightly.

I suggest to first measure the query performance and check your execution plans. Make sure that you create all the indexes that you need. If the query turns out to be still too slow, you might consider using a materialized view (called indexed view for sql server, see, e.g., [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx)). A materialized is quite like the table that you suggest, but it is kept in sync with your data automatically by the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

In a Datawarehouse context for analytics queries (pulling out numbers and statistics from your system) that could make sense, but for an oltp system regularly updated by users, a big lookup table is a very bad design, hard to maintain (lot of uneeded data: not all columns needed for all records etc), bad data etc.

Keeping out joins just for querying the system does not sounds like good  idea too
as it could break the work of Sql Server optimizer and has more chances to lead to table scans 
(that could be hard with a big table).

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/) is an interesting article from Joe Celko on big lookup tables, that sounds related to your problem, not exactly the same but could give you some insights.

A general advice would be : keep a normalized design (and especially for and oltp system).